# How to add many horizontal bars to each vertical bar?

Tags: python, excel, ggplot2, visualization, tableau-api

I want to create similar charts like the chart below, for each **vertical bars**, I want to add its **Top 10 values** as **horizontal bars** (not lines), but I can't figure out which tools should I use.

[image: Example of wanted output]

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to specify the other plots as a horizontal bar charts and they will appear on top of the first plot created. Here is how I plotted a horizontal bar chart over a vertical one. The data used made up for this so the graph is not very pretty but the code will be the same.

```
   N = 5
   menMeans = (20, 35, 30, 35, 27)
   womenMeans = (25, 32, 34, 20, 25)
   menStd = (2, 3, 4, 1, 2)
   womenStd = (3, 5, 2, 3, 3)
   ind = np.arange(N)    # the x locations for the groups
   y_pos = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]  #locations of the horizontal bars
   width = 0.35       # the width of the bars
   h_width = 1.0      #width of the horizontal bars
   h_x_loc = 1.18      #This will be used to change the x location of the 
                       #horizontal bars.

   p1 = plt.bar(ind, menMeans, width, yerr=menStd)
   p2 = plt.barh(y_pos, womenStd, width, left=h_x_loc, yerr=0)

   plt.ylabel('Scores')
   plt.title('Scores by group and gender')
   plt.xticks(ind, ('G1', 'G2', 'G3', 'G4', 'G5'))
   plt.yticks(np.arange(0, 81, 10))
   plt.legend((p1[0], p2[0]), ('Men', 'Women'))

   plt.show()
```

Note that to have each group of horizontal bars aligned with the correct corresponding vertical bar, you will need to make a separate plot for each group and change the x location for that group.

Comment: Thanks for sharing! But this is not what I want, for each vertical bars, I want to add its Top 10 values as the horizontal bars (not lines). Thank you again!

Comment: Ahh okay. For that you will need to make a separate horizontal plot for each of the vertical bars, then change their x positions to line up with the vertical bar that is references. I will update the code that I put in the answer to give an example of this.

Comment: I updated the code. It is a fairly simple change. Hope this helps!